# Correct play/stop mediaplayer android

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

I have a list view and a `MediaPlayer` that i use to play sounds based on row position (like a soundboard). The problem is that when a sound is playing, and another row is clicked (different position in list view), i would like to stop that sound and start new sound. This is my code, it works fine on play/stop on the same row, but not on different rows. How can i fix that?

```
public void playSound(int pos){


        if(isPlaying && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){  
            mMediaPlayer.stop();  
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            play.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
            play.invalidate();
            isPlaying = false;
    }

    else{
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, songs[pos]);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;
        play.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stop));
        play.invalidate();

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                isPlaying = false;
                play.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
                play.invalidate();
            }
        });

      }
    }
```

This is the onClick() method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;

vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);
                playSound(position);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Please post your onClick/onItemClick method for the listview

Comment: What is view? (the one you set the onclicklistener)

Comment: It's the view created by BaseAdapter. I edited the answer. @BlazeTama

Comment: Something wrong in your code. View vi = convertView;? vi is not used. Do you mean view is convertview?

Comment: Sorry i was wrong. view is vi. Now it's ok, just edited

Comment: Try to use log and see the clicked position. Is it always true? (despite of the player not working)